# Mongoose Update array in a document does not work as expected

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm scratching my head since a couple day on how to update the content of an array with Mongoose.

Here is my schema to begin with:

```
const playedGameSchema = new Schema ({
  created: Date,
  updated: Date,
  game: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'game'
  },
  creator: {
    id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
    },
    score: Number
  },
  partners: [{
    id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user'
    },
    score: Number
  }]
});
```

module.exports = mongoose.model('PlayedGame', playedGameSchema);

Basically, what I want to achieve is to, at the same time:
 - Update the creator.score (successful with dot notation).
 - Update the score key for each partner (unsuccessful).

Here is the result of a document created:

```
{
    "creator": {
        "id": "5b8544fa11235d9f02a9b4f1",
        "score": 0
    },
    "_id": "5bb6375f5f68cc5c52bc93ae",
    "game": "5b45080bb1806be939bfde03",
    "partners": [
        {
            "_id": "5bb637605f68cc5cafbc93b0",
            "id": "5b85497111235d677ba9b4f2",
            "score": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5bb637605f68ccc70ebc93af",
            "id": "5b85497111235d677ba9b4f2",
            "score": 0
        }
    ],
    "created": "2018-10-04T15:53:03.386Z",
    "updated": "2018-10-04T15:53:03.386Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

As I said, I was able to change the score of the score creator by passing something like `{ "creator.score": 500 }` as a second parameter, then I switch to trying to update the array.

Here is my lambda function to update the score for each partner:

```
export const update: Handler = (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  let partnersScore: object = {};

  if(body.update.partners) {
    body.update.partners.forEach((score, index) => {
      const key = `partners.${index}.$.score`;
      partnersScore = Object.assign(partnersScore, { [key]: score});
      console.log(partnersScore);
    });
  }

  connectToDatabase().then(() => {
    console.log('connected', partnersScore)
    PlayedGame.findByIdAndUpdate(body.id, { $set: { partners: partnersScore } },{ new: true})
      .then(game => cb(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: defaultResponseHeader,
        body: JSON.stringify(game)
      }))
      .catch(err => {
        cb(null, {
        statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: err
      })});
  });
}
```

Which passes a nice `{ 'partners.0.$.score': 500, 'partners.1.$.score': 1000 }` to the `$set`.

Unfortunately, the result to my request is a partners array that contains only one empty object.

```
{
    "creator": {
        "id": "5b8544fa11235d9f02a9b4f1",
        "score": 0
    },
    "_id": "5bb6375f5f68cc5c52bc93ae",
    "game": "5b45080bb1806be939bfde03",
    "partners": [
        {
            "_id": "5bb63775f6d99b7b76443741"
        }
    ],
    "created": "2018-10-04T15:53:03.386Z",
    "updated": "2018-10-04T15:53:03.386Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Can anyone guide me into updating the creator score and all partners score at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughs about findOneAndUpdate method on a model is that it's better because it doesn't require the data to be changed outside of the BDD, but wanting to update array keys and another key seems very difficult.

Instead, I relied on a set/save logic, like this:

```
PlayedGame.findById(body.id)
      .then(game => {
        game.set('creator.score',  update.creatorScore);
        update.partners.forEach((score, index) => game.set(`partners.${index}.score`, score));

        game.save()
          .then(result => {
            cb(null, {
              statusCode: 200,
              headers: defaultResponseHeader,
              body: JSON.stringify(result)
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            cb(null, {
            statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 'Update failed: ': err })
          })});
        })
```